# TestNG can't set progammatic default test name

Tags: java, testng

I'm trying with the following code to change the default test name, but still the value has remains as: default test name and not the test i set it to be:

```
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();

XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
suite.setName("Programmatic suite");



XmlTest xmlTest = new XmlTest(suite);
xmlTest.setName(testcase);
List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();
classes.add(new XmlClass(testsuite));
xmlTest.setXmlClasses(classes) ;
xmlTest.setName(testcase);


List<XmlTest> xmlTestsList = new ArrayList<XmlTest>();
xmlTestsList.add(xmlTest);
suite.setTests(xmlTestsList);


List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
suites.add(suite);

testng.setXmlSuites(suites);
testng.setTestNames(Arrays.asList(testcase));

    testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { autotestClass });
testng.addListener(tla);

testng.run();
```

Comment: Also i would like to comment that testng.setTestNames is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, basically added the call to the method:
testng.setDefaultTestName("your default testname");

Also i needed to implement the interface:
IMethodInterceptor